# Can we use Phantomjs to set a password to already existing pdf in java?

Tags: java, pdf, phantomjs

Can we use Phantomjs to set a password to an already existing pdf in java?
If so How?

Comment: I am using Phantomjs to generate pdf. but now I want to add password protection to that pdf using phantomjs

Comment: So, show what you did, and describe exactly what the problem is. Have you looked into whether PDF format supports this kind of protection at all? If yes, have you looked at whether your generator tools has this support? You obviously know more about your problem than I do, why don't you tell me?

Comment: As far as I tried I couldn't find any resources stating that PhantomJs supports PDF password protection.I could create PDF with ease but I couldn't find a method to add password protection using Phantomjs itself.

Comment: Cursory look at code (I assume this is `phantomjs-html2pdf`, since you haven't said otherwise) shows that there is no support for encryption, because most of that module is a wrapper for [webpage.render](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html), and that has no real support of encrypting contents (while it does natively support rendering to PDF).